# PHP Remove indexing from multidimensional array then shift array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 174
            [sec_id] => 36
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 175
            [sec_id] => 36
        )
)
```

This array generated using this method

```
$id_list = $this->input->post('to[]');
$sec_id     = $this->input->post("sec_id");
$new_arr = array();
foreach($id_list as $id){
    $new_arr[] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'sec_id' => $sec_id
);
}
```

I want to change the array to be something like this:

```
Array
(
Array
      (
        [id] => 174
        [sec_id] => 36
      ),
Array
    (
        [id] => 175
        [sec_id] => 36
       )
)
```

I need it this way so i can insert the data into DB using insert_batch() Codeigniter.

I have tried several ways. no luck.

Comment: _I have tried several ways..._ Post at least **1 way** you have been trying

Comment: Please add the code you've tried, we can help much better then. Also: what is the result you get with your code?

Comment: They look the same to me?

Comment: I have tried using array_map. arrays manipulation always been my weak skill. the above array is actually from a separate variables modified into an array. i will edit accordingly.

Comment: I can't think of any situation where having a key is even remotely a problem

Comment: if you want to reset your index then use `array_values()` function.

Comment: @AmQ7 Both arrays you've written are the same. Array in any case has index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of **Codeigniter**

```
$data = array(
            array(
                    'title' => 'My title',
                    'name' => 'My Name',
                    'date' => 'My date'
            ),
            array(
                    'title' => 'Another title',
                    'name' => 'Another Name',
                    'date' => 'Another date'
            )
    );

    $this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

if you use **print_r($data);** you have this result..An array must be has index.

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => My title
            [name] => My Name
            [date] => My date
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Another title
            [name] => Another Name
            [date] => Another date
        )

)
```

Comment: hahahah I have solve it last night at 6am then went to sleep. First thing i did was posting it as a questions. lol. Sorry StackOverflow. thx @pedram shabani